# Gegenderte Komposita mit der Mehrzahl?

Tags: genitive, compound

Gendern ist ja in gewissen Kreisen recht Mode geworden. Dass dabei keine Rücksicht auf Grammatik, Sprache oder Logik genommen wird, auch.

Nun lese ich manchmal Dinge wie *Kund**innen**nummer* (anstelle *Kund**en**nummer*) und frage mich folgendes:

Eine Kundennummer ist ja ‚die Nummer des Kund**en**‘ oder eben ‚des Kund**en** Nummer‘ ⇒ *Kund**en**nummer*. Wenn man das ganze jetzt mit der weiblichen Form machen würde, müsste es dann nicht *Kund**in**nummer* heißen? ‚Die Nummer der Kund**in**‘, ‚der Kund**in** Nummer‘ ⇒  *Kund**in**nummer*?

Ist meine Annahme/mein Verständnis falsch?

Comment: Es ist gar nicht gesagt, dass "Kunden" in "Kundennummer" Mehrzahl ist. Es heißt ja auch Bestellnummer, Ausweisnummer und Telephonnummer. Das zweite "n" kann auch ein Fugenlaut sein, der das weichere Sprechen erlaubt, ganz im  Kontrast zur Innenarchitekt_innenlücke, die das Gegenteil ist, eine Sprach-, Hör- und Lesbarriere. Zwar heißt es auch Orangensaft aber nicht Äpfelsaft.

Comment: Ich habe sämtliche Kommentare, die hier allgemein über das Gendern diskutieren, gelöscht. Sie sind hier off-topic. Ich verstehe, dass die Frage, und die Art wie sie gestellt ist, dazu einlädt, aber solche Diskussionen bringen hier nichts, und gehören auch nicht in die Kommentare. Wenn ihr eure Freude an der Diskussion nicht bändigen könnt, kann ich noch den Chat empfehlen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ergänzung zur Antwort von @infinitezero: Bei Komposita wie 'Kundennummer' steht der erste Teil üblicherweise im Nominativ, gelegentlich im Plural:

> Kundennummer
> Schweinebauch
> Mitgliederliste
> Wörterbuch
> Tomatensalat

Insofern bildet man Kundinnennummer analog als Nominativ Plural von Kundin: Kundinnen.

Den Genitiv findet man als ersten Teil eines Kompositums selten:

> Schweinsgalopp

wobei man den durchaus auch als 'Schweinegalopp' bilden kann.

Comment: Ist das sicher ein Genitiv, und nicht etwa ein Fugen-s?

Comment: Kann auch ein Fugen-s sein... :)

Comment: Die Beispiele "Mitgliederliste" und "Wörterbuch" passen nicht. Es ist klar, dass es um mehrere Mitglieder und Wörter geht. Außerdem heißt es hier "Mitgliedsnummer" und nicht "Mitgliedernummer".

Answer (score 2):

Am Wort "Kundennummer" selbst lässt sich nicht ablesen, ob hier *Kunde* im Singular (Nr. des Kunden) oder *Kunden* im Plural gemeint ist. Da die Nummer aber **eine** Person eindeutig identifizieren soll, scheint mir die Singular-Interpretation logischer zu sein. Daher also "Kundinnummer".

Zur eindeutigen Identifikation gibt es ja auch Rechnungsnummer, Kontonummer etc. Hier ist schon grammatikalisch klar, dass "Rechnung" und "Konto" im Singular sind. Eine ähnliche Situation wie bei Kundennummer gibt es bei "Zählernummer". Ist hier (Strom-) Zähler im Singular oder im Plural gemeint? Ich glaube nicht, dass jemand hier die Plural-Variante für korrekt hält.

Nachtrag:

Das Wort "Mitgliedsnummer" kann als gutes Analogon zu "Kundennummer" dienen. Hier wird der Singular verwendet.

Comment: Heißt das, dass Orangensaft aus vielen Orangen, aber Apfelsaft aus nur einem Apfel gewonnen wird?

Comment: @userunknown Hier zeigt sich die wunderbare Klarheit des Hessischen: Mir trinke Ebbelwoi.

Comment: Die Moselfranken saufen konfliktscheu Viez. :)

Comment: Die Alterrnative ist nicht Kunden im Plural vs. Kunde im Singular, sondern vs. Kunde als Klasse. Der Satz "Der Pinguin ist auf der Südhalbkugel heimisch" spricht nicht von einem einzelnen, bestimmten Pinguin sondern vom Pinguin als Klasse. Das Wort steht natürlich dennoch im Singular, während Kunden in Kdnr. im Plural steht. Apfelsaft ist ja nicht der Saft eines einzelnen Apfels.

Comment: @userunknown: Während *Kunde* eindeutig Singular ist, kann *Kunden* auch der Wortstamm mit angehängtem Fugen-n sein, ebenso wie *Heldentat* nur selten die Tat mehrerer Helden beschreibt.

Comment: Die Möglichkeit des Fugenlauts ist mir bewusst. Mir scheint die ganze Fragestellung Einzahl/Mehrzahl ein Holzweg zu sein. Ein Fahrradkorso besteht ja nicht nur aus einem einzelnen Fahrrad, dennoch heißt es nicht Fahrräderkorso.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist nicht völlig klar. An dieser Stelle:

> müsste es dann nicht "Kundinnummer" heissen

wird eine normative Frage gestellt, eine Sollens-Frage, eine Frage danach, wie etwas heißen muss, oder hier eben: "müsste". Eine normative Frage kann aber nur auf der Grundlage einer allgemein akzeptierten Norm beantwortet werden. Diese allgemein akzeptierte Norm ist hier nicht gegeben. Das gilt einerseits für die Sprache im Allgemeinen, weswegen normative Fragen in der Linguistik immer problematisch sind, und beim Gendern im Besonderen: Gendern ist ein Phänomen des [Sprachwandels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachwandel?), daher taugen die althergebrachten Regeln der Sprache gerade nicht dazu, gegenderte Sprache zu bewerten.

Die Frage ist also ziemlich unklar. In meiner Antwort versuche ich verschiedene Möglichkeiten zu erörtern:

A) Geht man davon aus, dass der erste Bestandteil von *Kundennummer* aus dem Genitiv Singular von *der Kunde* gebildet ist, dann wäre *Kundinnummer* die engere Analogie zu *Kundennummer*.

B) Geht man davon aus, dass der erste Bestandteil von *Kundennummer* aus dem Nominativ Plural von *der Kunde* gebildet ist, dann wäre *Kundinnenummer* die engere Analogie zu *Kundennummer*.

Unabhängig davon, welche der beiden genannten Konzeptionalisierungen man *Kundennummer* zugrunde legt, ist diese Analyse aber gar nicht geeignet, die Frage zu beantworten. Denn der Frage liegt eine implizite Prämisse zugrunde, die nicht gegeben ist. Diese Prämisse lautet:

*Gegenderte Begriffe müssen grammatisch analog zu den Begriffen des generischen Maskulinums gebildet werden.*

Und diese implizite Prämisse ist willkürlich, d.h. man kann an sie glauben, oder auch nicht. Sie kommt aus dem Nichts.

Die Frage spiegelt ein allgemein verbreitetes Missverständniss wider, dass es in der Sprache *logische*, d.h. *zwingende* regulative Zusammenhänge geben müsste. Sprachliche Regeln sind aber nicht logisch, sondern konventionell. Konzeptionelle Einfachheit kann sich mitunter aus der Befolgung einer logischen Regel ergeben, mitunter kann aber die logische Anwendung einer Regel der Einfachheit auch im Wege stehen. Darüberhinaus bestimmen neben der Einfachheit auch noch viele andere Faktoren mit, welche Konventionen sich durchsetzen. Viele dieser Faktoren sind nicht "logischer" oder auch nur kognitionspsychologischer Natur, sondern sozialer Natur.

Das alles ist, wohlgemerkt, keine Besonderheit des Sprachphänomens des Genderns, sondern gilt ganz allgemein für Sprache. Wäre die Entwicklung der Sprache aus irgendeiner Sicht logisch zwingend, dann könnte es ja nur eine "richtige" Sprache geben, und es wäre dann doch seltsam, dass gerade das Deutsch der zweiten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts diese einzig richtige, weil logisch zwingende Sprache sein sollte.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132272/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-scholbach-gegenderte-komposita-mit-der-mehrzahl).

Comment: Schöne Antwort, nur fehlt Fall C: „Geht man davon aus, dass der erste Bestandteil von _Kundennummer_ aus dem Wortstamm _Kund-_ oder dem NomSg _der Kunde_ und einem Fugenelement gebildet ist, …“

Comment: @Crissov Guter Punkt. Was wäre deiner Meinung nach in diesem Fall das Resultat der Analogie?

Comment: Naja, eigentlich wäre damit die Prämisse hinfällig, also _Kundennummer_. Wenn es wirklich auf _Kundin_ beruhen soll, dann _Kundinnennummer_ oder möglicherweise sogar _Kundinsnummer_.

Answer (score -1):

Kundennummer kann nicht nur die Nummer des Kunden sondern auch der Kunden sein (Plural). Beim Gendern wird üblicherweise das generische Maskulinum durch eine Form ersetzt, die verdeutlichen soll, dass alle Geschlechter inkludiert sind. Kunden -> +Kund*innen/KundInnen_. Dazu gibt es noch das generische Femininum *Kundinnen* (kleines i, statt großes Binnen-i).

Um jetzt also alle explizit einzubeziehen, wird das Kompositum also aus dem gegenderten Wort gebildet:

> Kundinnennummer, Kund*innennummer, KundInnennummer.

Wenn es explizit um die Einzahl gehen soll, ginge auch

> Kundinnummer, Kund*innummer

Comment: Aber wenn es sich klar um die Nummer _eines_ Kunden handelt, wieso heisst es dann nicht Kundinnummer? Wenn auf meinem Lieferschein steht "Kundennummer", ist es doch klar, dass es sich um meine Kundennummer handelt und soweit ich weiss sind die meisten Menschen Einzelpersonen... Also ergibt Kundinnennummer nicht so richtig Sinn, ausser ich übersehe etwas.